# 5X5 button matrix with 433Mhz rf module or NRF module

Tags: arduino, embedded, 433mhz, nrf24l01

I have interfaced 433Mhz rf module and custom 5x5 button matrix with arduino. Keeping Keypad matrix at transmitter side and an LED on the reciever side as long as i hold down the button the led should glow, this is what i have in mind.

Using Keypad.h library i am able to send signal with all 25 buttons, the issue is that it is sending signal only once and not continuously even if i keep pressing the button and hence the led is not glowing while pressing the button down it just turns on and does not go off

Is 433Mhz rf module capable of doing so or do i have to change module and try something else?

I want to do two things

1. Sending continuous signal with buttons kept pressed
2. Multiple button press

Can anyone help me?

for the reference i'll share the code

```
Transmitter Code

// Include RadioHead Amplitude Shift Keying Library
#include <RH_ASK.h>
// Include dependant SPI Library 
#include <SPI.h> 
//Include Keypad matrix Library
#include <Keypad.h>
// int push = 13;

const byte ROWS = 5; //four rows
const byte COLS = 5; //four columns
//define the cymbols on the buttons of the keypads
char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'A','B','C','D','E'},
  {'F','G','H','I','J'},
  {'K','L','M','N','O'},
  {'P','Q','R','S','T'},
  {'U','V','W','X','Y'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {2,3,4,5,6}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {7,8,9,10,11}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

//initialize an instance of class NewKeypad
Keypad customKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);



char holdKey;
unsigned long t_hold;

// Create Amplitude Shift Keying Object
RH_ASK rf_driver;
 
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    // Initialize ASK Object
    rf_driver.init();
    //pinMode(push, INPUT);
}
 
void loop()
{
    char key = customKeypad.getKey();
 
   if (key){
     holdKey = key;
     Serial.println(key);
   }
 
   if (customKeypad.getState() == HOLD) {
      if ((millis() - t_hold) > 100 ) {
          if (holdKey == 'A'){
              Serial.println("A");
              const char *msg = "A";
              rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
              rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
              Serial.print("released");
              }   

          if (holdKey == 'B'){
              Serial.println("B");
              const char *msg = "B";
              rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
              rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
              }

         if (holdKey == 'C'){
              Serial.println("C");
              const char *msg = "C";
              rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
              rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
              }


         if (holdKey == 'D'){
              Serial.println("D");
              const char *msg = "D";
              rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
              rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
              }

        if (holdKey == 'E'){
             Serial.println("E");
             const char *msg = "E";
             rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
             rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
             }

        if (holdKey == 'F'){
            Serial.println("F");
            const char *msg = "F";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'G'){
            Serial.println("G");
            const char *msg = "G";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'H'){
            Serial.println("H");
            const char *msg = "H";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'I'){
            Serial.println("I");
            const char *msg = "I";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'J'){
            Serial.println("J");
            const char *msg = "J";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'K'){
            Serial.println("K");
            const char *msg = "K";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'L'){
            Serial.println("L");
            const char *msg = "L";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'M'){
            Serial.println("M");
            const char *msg = "M";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'N'){
            Serial.println("N");
            const char *msg = "N";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'O'){
            Serial.println("O");
            const char *msg = "O";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

       if (holdKey == 'P'){
            Serial.println("P");
            const char *msg = "P";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'Q'){
            Serial.println("Q");
            const char *msg = "Q";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'R'){
            Serial.println("R");
            const char *msg = "R";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'S'){
            Serial.println("S");
            const char *msg = "S";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'T'){
            Serial.println("T");
            const char *msg = "T";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'U'){
            Serial.println("U");
            const char *msg = "U";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'V'){
            Serial.println("V");
            const char *msg = "V";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'W'){
            Serial.println("W");
            const char *msg = "W";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'X'){
            Serial.println("X");
            const char *msg = "X";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }

        if (holdKey == 'Y'){
            Serial.println("Y");
            const char *msg = "Y";
            rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
            rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
            }
          }Serial.println("1");   
      }
       const char *msg = "0";
       rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
       rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
       Serial.println("2");
   }
```

`````
Reciever code

// Include RadioHead Amplitude Shift Keying Library
#include <RH_ASK.h>
// Include dependant SPI Library 
#include <SPI.h> 

// Create Amplitude Shift Keying Object
RH_ASK rf_driver;

void setup()
{
    // Initialize ASK Object
    rf_driver.init();
    // Setup Serial Monitor
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{

  //digitalWrite(12, HIGH);  
    // Set buffer to size of expected message
    uint8_t buf[24];
    uint8_t buflen = sizeof(buf);
    // Check if received packet is correct size
    if (rf_driver.recv(buf, &buflen))
    {
      
      // Message received with valid checksum
      //Serial.print("Message Received: ");
      //Serial.println((char*)buf);   
      for (int i; i < buflen; i++){
//      switch(buf[i]){
//
//        case 'A':
//          digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
//          break;
//
//        case 'B':
//          digitalWrite(8, LOW);
//          break;
//
//        //default:
//          //digitalWrite(8, LOW);
//          //Serial.println("This is default");
//        
//        }
        //Serial.print("my data=");
        Serial.write(buf[0]);
        if(buf[i]=='A'){
          //Serial.println("Forward");
          digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
          Serial.println("LED ON");
          }

          else if(buf[i]=='0'){
          //Serial.println("123");
          digitalWrite(8, LOW);
          Serial.println("LED OFF");
          }

         if(buf[i]=='B'){
          //Serial.println("Forward");
          digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
          Serial.println("LED ON");
          }

          else if(buf[i]=='0'){
          //Serial.println("123");
          digitalWrite(8, LOW);
          Serial.println("LED OFF");
          }

         if(buf[i]=='C'){
          //Serial.println("Forward");
          digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
          Serial.println("LED ON");
          }

          else if(buf[i]=='0'){
          //Serial.println("123");
          digitalWrite(8, LOW);
          Serial.println("LED OFF");
          }

         if(buf[i]=='D'){
          //Serial.println("Forward");
          digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
          Serial.println("LED ON");
          }

          else if(buf[i]=='0'){
          //Serial.println("123");
          digitalWrite(8, LOW);
          Serial.println("LED OFF");
          }

         if(buf[i]=='E'){
          //Serial.println("Forward");
          digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
          Serial.println("LED ON");
          }

          else if(buf[i]=='0'){
          //Serial.println("123");
          digitalWrite(8, LOW);
          Serial.println("LED OFF");
          }

          if(buf[i]=='F'){
          //Serial.println("Forward");
          digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
          Serial.println("LED ON");
          }

          else if(buf[i]=='0'){
          //Serial.println("123");
          digitalWrite(8, LOW);
          Serial.println("LED OFF");
          }

          if(buf[i]=='G'){
          //Serial.println("Forward");
          digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
          Serial.println("LED ON");
          }

          else if(buf[i]=='0'){
          //Serial.println("123");
          digitalWrite(8, LOW);
          Serial.println("LED OFF");
          }

      
    }
}}


````
`````

Comment: Hi! Welcome here. You need to ask a precise question!

Comment: In order to help you, you need to provide more information: the exact type of 5x5 button matrix you are using, the exact behavior you want to implement (should a single press turn the LED on and another press off, or should the LED be on as long as the button is held down?), the exact behavior for multiple button presses etc. Since directly connecting a single button works, the RF module is probably not relevant for the question. It would be better to omit it and simplify the question. And most likely the Arduino code is relevant as well. So show the relevant part.

Comment: ok I'll edit m question and put all these things.. Thanks

Comment: Are you transmitting both button_activated and button_deactivated signals? It seems to me that you are just sending the activated signal.

Comment: In transmittor section   
```` C     
      const char *msg = "0";
       rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
       rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
       Serial.println("2");
````
This part is my deactivating signal

Comment: the desired operation makes no sense ... it cannot differentiate between key held down and key pressed multiple times .... sending a kepress only once is the way to go ... just send key release events also ... on receiving side, keep track of key presses and releases .... on receiving side, light an LED if any keys are registered as being pressed .... define a 25 byte array to hold the status of the keys

Comment: you could also transmit the status of all the keys continuously

Comment: objective 1 is against the rules of 433Mhz (it should be an intermittent transmitter, not continuous)

Comment: How do you debounce the buttons? Software or hardware?

Comment: @Jasen Not at all, the 433MHz band have very different requirements in different countries. EU has attempted to make it 10% duty cycle but most member states has so far responded to that attempt with the middle finger. You can make continuous SRD transmitters that are classified to ETSI 300 220 long as you stick below 10mW ERP and that's fine in most countries.

Comment: Specifically EU 2006/771/EC, band no 45c. 434,04-434,79 MHz, 100% duty cycle, 10mW ERP, 25kHz channel spacing. This is for non-specific SRD and applies to the whole of EU (and I assume still the UK too).

Comment: The idea is to make a multifunction remote for an RC car with macnum wheel.. Right, left, forward, backward, side to side diagonally up and down plus other functions and i wanted to make it by using 433Mhz or NRF module